# Fields changed in beforeUpdate not persisted

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, interceptor

In my Grails 3.1.14 app I have a domain class:

```
class MyDomain {

  String text

  def beforeInsert() { beforeUpdate() }

  def beforeUpdate() {
    text = changeTextBasedOnOtherFields()
    println ">>> $text"
    true
  }
}
```

in a controller the instance gets saved with `myDomain.save flush:true`.

The problem is, that the `text` property is ignored by saving, although I can see the println's output with a proper value in a console.

If I put the text changing code just in front of saving:

```
myDomain.text = changeTextBasedOnOtherFields()
myDomain.save flush:true
```

then it works like charm!

Any way to solve the mistery?

Comment: Co-incidence, I experienced the same exact issue yesterday in Grail 3.1.9 with Mongodb.

Comment: i am experiencing the same in 3.3.11

Comment: @corrego see my answer down below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a GORM-gotcha.

Instead of using a `property` in interceptor-methods, one should use a `setter`:

```
def beforeUpdate() {
  setText changeTextBasedOnOtherFields()
  true
}
```